# Product collection by category , in stock

Tags: product, category, stock

I am working on product collection scenario, i want product collection with categories filter with in stock collection.

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit vague bit here goes

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load([category id]);

$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
   ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
   ->addAttributeToSelect([... attributes you need ...]);

Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_collection);
```